# Handling potential sql injection in Python 3.7 with pymysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I am new to Python. I have written following piece of code:

```
    sql = f"UPDATE my_table SET active=1, updated_at=%s WHERE id=%s"
    params = [(k, v) for k, v in data_dict.items()]

    for param in params:
        curr_sql_query = sql % param
        self.db_obj.execute(curr_sql_query)
```

Here `db_obj` internally uses `pymysql` Is there any chance of potential sql injection in the above code ? If any, could you please suggest approach to handle it ? Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/README.rst#example) shows how to do it right by giving the arguments to `execute()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @KlausD for your response. I have gone through this. The code I specified in the OP does not seem to be consistent with approach suggested in the documentation. So I will update accordingly.